# showing structure view for python files using jedi-vim

Tags: python, vim, jedi-vim

Does jedi vim support anything like intellijs https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structure-tool-window-file-structure-popup.html ?

Comment: It's not jedi in charge of the feature. nerdtree or something others.

Comment: No, at the moment this is not a Jedi feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [majutsushi/tagbar](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar) which does this pretty well actually. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJiOYNMOQ8M) explains how it works with ruby too.

Answer (score 4):

This very simple command gives you an actionable outline of your document:

```
:g/def\|class/#
```

You can map it if you don't want to type it all the time; and make it a bit cleaner in the same move:

```
augroup PythonStuff
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> <F12> :<C-u>g/\<def\>\\|\<class\>/#<CR>
augroup END
```

Comment: I wonder, is it possible to set automatically a mark at every of these points?

Comment: It should be possible to put a mark on the 26 first matches with a bit of vimscript, yes. How would you use those marks?

Comment: Well, my thought wasn't exactly about Python (where you can use `gd` and the likes) but more about other kind of structured text. And in general, how can this be achieved? Collecting these "points of interest" into a list, and then assigning marks to list elements? Or is there some other way around, what do you think?

Comment: The technical part doesn't sound hard at all. It's the "business" part that needs a bit of thinking. For example, it will be impossible for anyone to remember 26 mark ↔︎ symbol mappings. An obvious workaround would be to use signs but that introduces complexity. A lightweight, on-demand, actionable TOC seems enough to me.

Comment: In my particular case it's kinda 8-10 marks at the **very** maximum :) (more like 5). Also, since I'm not a programmer, the technical part doesn't seem extremely obvious to me :). For example, how to actually collect those "points of interest"?

Comment: I would `:help :redir` the output of the command I posted to a variable, `:help map()` lines to letters and `:help :mark` every line with its corresponding letter in a `:help :for` loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148677/discussion-between-a-s-and-romainl).